# Jquery simplyScroll multiple scrollers on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplyscroll

I needs to use Jquery simplyScroll plugging few times on my page like few scrollers Here i am posting the code please help. I tried to do that my self with this code but i am unable to complete it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/jquery.simplyscroll-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/jquery.simplyscroll-1.0.4.css" media="all" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
            autoMode: 'loop'
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>


<div class="simply-scroll simply-scroll-container"><div class="simply-scroll-back"></div><div class="simply-scroll-forward"></div><div class="simply-scroll-clip">
<ul id="scroller" class="simply-scroll-list" style="width: 2895px; ">
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080608_9N3H5GYL_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse"></li>
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080513_4D3SD1BQ_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Chloe nightclub"></li>
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080513_VPJWVQRW_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse bar"></li>
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080514_B1YJ08B6_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse chloe club fishtank"></li>
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080514_JYW68XPT_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse restaurant"></li>
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080608_38CG51J2_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse"></li>
            <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080608_9N3H5GYL_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse"></li><li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080513_4D3SD1BQ_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Chloe nightclub"></li></ul></div></div>

            <div class="simply-scroll simply-scroll-container"><div class="simply-scroll-back"></div><div class="simply-scroll-forward"></div><div class="simply-scroll-clip">
<ul id="scroller" class="simply-scroll-list" style="width: 2895px; ">
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080608_9N3H5GYL_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse"></li>
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080513_4D3SD1BQ_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Chloe nightclub"></li>
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080513_VPJWVQRW_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse bar"></li>
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080514_B1YJ08B6_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse chloe club fishtank"></li>
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080514_JYW68XPT_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse restaurant"></li>
                <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080608_38CG51J2_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse"></li>
            <li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080608_9N3H5GYL_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse"></li><li><img src="./jQuery simplyScroll - Logicbox_files/20080513_4D3SD1BQ_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Chloe nightclub"></li></ul></div></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can not use one and the same id multiple times. and before it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use one and the same id multiple times. and before it does not work

something lik this

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
            autoMode: 'loop'
        });


        $("#scroller1").simplyScroll({
            autoMode: 'loop'
        });


        $("#scroller2").simplyScroll({
            autoMode: 'loop'
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you are welcome , and u can use classes  somthing like this $(".scroller").simplyScroll({
            autoMode: 'loop'
        });

and just one class

Answer (score 1):

You can use `class` instead of `id` for multiple scroller. I hope it will help you.

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(".scroller").simplyScroll({
            autoMode: 'loop'
        });
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Don't use id and use class some thing like this

```
<ul class="scroller simply-scroll-list" style="width: 2895px; ">....</ul>
<ul class="scroller simply-scroll-list" style="width: 2895px; ">....</ul>
```